# asp.net 5 using DNX

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dnx50

I am running into an issue trying to include the following in the project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
```

It gives me the following error:

**The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Securitu.Cookies 1.0.0-beta3 in project TestApp does not support framework DNX, Version=v4.5.1**

as well as:

**The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Securitu.Cookies 1.0.0-beta3 in project TestApp does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0**

These are my framworks specified:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

And here is my complete list of dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

So the question is, if it is not supported "cookies" what can i use instead?, i have tried to look around but have not had any luck.

I want to add security to a small app i am building, any better suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNet.Securitu" is probably not the correct spelling. You also have a very strange mix of beta2, beta4, beta5, beta7, beta8 and rc1-final which could cause some trouble.

Comment: alternative could be to use BearerToken using OWIN/OAUTH  OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {

                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/authtoken"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things incorrect about what you're doing:

1. You are mixing beta2, beta4, beta5, beta8, and rc1 packages. Since there's a lot of churn between releases, that's a recipe for disaster. Try to stick to a single release (rc1 is the latest stable).
2. [Microsoft.AspNet.Security.* has been renamed](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/12). If you have other packages for which you cannot find the `rc1` version, search the Announcements repo to see if they got renamed.